# Android, does foreground service keep app alive?

Tags: java, android, service, kill, foreground

Will Android kill `public class App extends Application` if there is a foreground service running?

I am not sure if it's even important... If I have a reference from that service to a object instantiated in Activity or App and that Activity/App gets killed, will reference from the service still be valid?

Last question is... What happens with static fields if app associated with the class containing the static fields gets killed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will Android kill public class App extends Application if there is a foreground service running?

Classes are not "killed" in Android. Processes are terminated. An `Application` instance is created when your process is created, and it remains around until the process is terminated.

So long as the foreground service is running, it's process is alive (by definition), and its `Application` will remain around.

> What happens with static fields if app associated with the class containing the static fields gets killed?

Again, classes are not "killed" in Android. Processes are terminated. When your process is terminated, everything in memory goes away, including `static` fields and their references.

Comment: Android documentation says _Foreground services must display a Notification._ If I want this notification to show updated UI, like when the user swipes it down I want to make a network call to get the data. I was wondering if there is a way to know that the user swiped it down?

Comment: @Prudhvi: You are not informed about that event. The expectation is that you would keep the notification content up to date as the data changes.

Comment: @Prudhvi If you call the service again, the notification is created again. But I don't if the user swiping down the notification bar can be recognized.