Does it make sense to check for nullity of an Application instance in a foreground service?
I use BleApp : Application() to store BluetoohDevice, BluetoothGattCharacteristic and some state booleans. I access all of these properties from my foreground service BleService and from activities. The BleService should be responsible for sending a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) message to a BLE peripheral (LED display) each time it receives a BLE message from a smartwatch.
Is it possible that my BleService would run independently of the app process? I mean, I don't want that, I'm just asking if it is possible that the reference to the BleApp used in my BleService would somehow become null? For example, what if I use START_STICKY in the onStartCommand and the system kills the process due to low memory and then restarts the service when the memory becomes available again? Would be the BleApp also available again, so I can use it's properties and methods from the foreground service?
I have minSdk = 31 and targetSdk = 34.
I have tried adb shell am kill <package.name>, but it does not seem to kill anything, the app process and the foreground service was still running. I am testing on a physical device, because of Bluetooth usage.
I have read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49070879/android-does-foreground-service-keep-app-alive. From the answer, it seems that as long as the BleService is running, the BleApp should be valid too.
But what really confuses me is that anytime I asked Bing's Copilot, it consistently answers that a foreground service can continue executing even if he app's process is killed by Android. So, where is the truth?

I think you should add logs to get Application.getProcessName(). That will give you a hint - in which exact process your service is running.

"foreground service can continue executing even if the app's process is killed by Android". This does not make sense as the foreground service code runs within the app process.
